# Rearrange array index Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, unset

I have an error after delete an element from an array of laravel eloquent

A property has rooms

```
foreach ($property->rooms as $key => $room) {
    if ($room->type == 1 and $type ==1 and $room->price < $price->min or $room->price > $price->max) {
            print_r($property->rooms);
            unset($property->rooms[$key]);
            //$array = array_values($property->rooms); doesn't work
            print_r($property->rooms);
        }
    }
```

When i encode this into a json, the array is convert into an object not an array

**Before unset**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Room Object
            (
                [table:protected] => rooms
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => properties_id
                        [1] => price
                        [2] => is_available
                        [3] => type
                        [4] => description
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 450000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-20 22:27:44
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 450000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-20 22:27:44
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

        [1] => Room Object
            (
                [table:protected] => rooms
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => properties_id
                        [1] => price
                        [2] => is_available
                        [3] => type
                        [4] => description
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 350000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-21 18:13:15
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 350000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-21 18:13:15
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

        [2] => Room Object
            (
                [table:protected] => rooms
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => properties_id
                        [1] => price
                        [2] => is_available
                        [3] => type
                        [4] => description
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 250000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 250000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

**After unset**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [1] => Room Object
            (
                [table:protected] => rooms
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => properties_id
                        [1] => price
                        [2] => is_available
                        [3] => type
                        [4] => description
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 350000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-21 18:13:15
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 350000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 2014-10-21 18:13:15
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

        [2] => Room Object
            (
                [table:protected] => rooms
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => properties_id
                        [1] => price
                        [2] => is_available
                        [3] => type
                        [4] => description
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 250000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [properties_id] => 4
                        [price] => 250000
                        [is_available] => 1
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [type] => 1
                        [description] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

**converted into a json the rooms field should be an array not an object:**

```
{"other_parameters": "something","rooms":{"1":{"id":2,"properties_id":4,"price":350000,"is_available":1,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"2014-10-21 18:13:15","type":1,"description":null},"2":{"id":3,"properties_id":4,"price":250000,"is_available":1,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","type":1,"description":""}}}
```

Comment: please can you post the original php object for $property->rooms

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have found a solution in the laravel documentation.

after modifying the array, you have to call a method from laravel collection named values() that arrange the array indexes, example:

```
unset($property->rooms[$key]);
$property->rooms->values();
```

Comment: where did you find this in the documentation? @Miguel

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
$array = array();
foreach ($property->rooms as $key => $room) {
    if ($room->type == 1) {
        unset($property->rooms->{$key}); <<-- pay attention to this
    } else {
        $array[] = get_object_vars($room); // sort the passed row into new array
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

**Option 2**

To convert from JSON to Array set the assoc flag to **TRUE**:

```
json_decode('Your json script', true);

foreach ($property['rooms'] as $key => $room) {
    if ($room['type'] == 1) {
        unset($property['rooms'][$key]);
    }
}
$array = array_values($property['rooms']); 
print_r($array);
```