# How to array_values laravel collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a search result from `image` model and `$photo` saved the data which `$photo->type == 'photo'`.

```
$photo = $image->filter(function($photo,$key) use($path){
    if($photo->type == 'photo'){
        $photo->url = $path.$photo->image;
             return $photo;
    }
});
```

Here is the `$photo` collection and is there any way to `array_values()` the `items` data?

```
Collection {#352 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    2 => ImageBanquet {#349 ▶}
    3 => ImageBanquet {#350 ▶}
    4 => ImageBanquet {#351 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rearrange array index Eloquent Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309747/rearrange-array-index-eloquent-laravel)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values) collection helper.

```
$values = $collection->values();
```